# Consume SOAP Web Service in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, soap

I'm trying to find info on how to consume a SOAP service using Swift in iOS. I'm used to using REST web services but I don't have that luxury in this case. I have the wsdl. The request for one of the methods I need to use looks like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:fet="http://www.kyfb.com/ebuz/FetcheBuzAccountInfo/">
<soapenv:Header>
      <wsse:Security soapenv:actor="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/actor/next" soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
         <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="SecurityToken-6138db82-5a4c-4bf7-915f-af7a10d9ae96" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:Username>ebusdoc</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password>Ebusnes1</wsse:Password>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>

   <soapenv:Body>
      <fet:fetchInformationForGuest>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <FetchInformationForGuestReq>
         <entityNbr>0001354648</entityNbr>
            <entityType>MBR</entityType>
         </FetchInformationForGuestReq>
      </fet:fetchInformationForGuest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I know how to actually parse XML in Swift, but I'm not sure how to get the response using this request. Any help here is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
open class HTTPSOAPClient {

open static let sharedInstance = HTTPSOAPClient()// Singleton instance yo use throughout the app
fileprivate init() {} //This prevents others from using the default '()' initializer for this class.


public func sendRequest(_ method: Alamofire.HTTPMethod,url: String, parameters: String, header: [String: String]?,completionHandler: @escaping (NSString)-> Void)  {
    var url = url
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let str:String = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'><soap:Body>" + parameters + "</soap:Body></soap:Envelope>"
    let postData = NSData(data: str.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string:url)!)
    request.addValue("text/xml; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = postData as Data
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task =  session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, resp, error) in

        guard error == nil && data != nil else{

            print("connection error or data is nill")

            return
        }

        if resp != nil {



        }

        let mutableData : Void = NSMutableData.initialize()
        print(mutableData)


        let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        completionHandler(dataString!)

        print(dataString ?? "")
     }

    task.resume()
  }
}
```

call sendRequest as Below

```
HTTPSOAPClient.sharedInstance.sendRequest(<#T##method: HTTPMethod##HTTPMethod#>, url: <#T##String#>, parameters: <#T##String#>, header: <#T##[String : String]?#>, completionHandler: <#T##(NSString) -> Void#>)
```